# How to get data with ID

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on Comic Reader app, and I want to code a Latest Updates page where all the new Chapters appear, I made 2 Firebase Database Childs one is for the Comics containing all the information and Chapters, and one called LatestUpdates only containing ID's of the coresponding comics.

How Can I use the ID's of the "LatestUpdates" Child to get the childs from "Comic"?

[image]

Currently my code gets the LatestUpdates childs with a for loop:

```
private void LoadLastUpdated() {
    latest.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        List<Comic> comic_load = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshotcomic : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), snapshotcomic.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            comicListener.onComicLoadDoneListener(comic_load);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can't you create a reference to the other path based on the `snapshotcomic.getKey()` and then call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` (or `getData()`) on that?

Comment: There is a Reference for the other path already, the feature Im trying to implement is a Latest Updates page, where people can see the latest updated comics. So my question was how Could I use the ID's to get the coresponding child in the other path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how Could I use the ID's to get the coresponding child in the other path.

To create a reference to the Comic from a snapshot of the `latestUpdates` child node you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference comicsRef = dbInstance.getReference("Comic");
DatabaseReference comicRef = comicsRef.child(snapshotcomic.getValue(String.class));
```

And then you can call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `getData` on that `comicRef`.